# Send haproxy logs to cloudwatch

Tags: haproxy, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs

We're running an haproxy container on ECS and struggling to setup logging.

The ECS container definition contains the log configuration set out in the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)

```
"logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs",
    "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "haproxy_logs",
        "awslogs-region": "us-east-1"
 }
```

And the haproxy.cfg has some default configuration settings -

```
global
  log     127.0.0.1 local1 notice
defaults  
  log     global
```

However we're just getting a single duplicated log entry in cloud watch -

```
<7>haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -p /run/haproxy.pid -f /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -Ds
```

There's no record of http requests. And I can't find any logs in the haproxy container itself.